# Should I use both striptags() and htmlspecialchars() to prevent XSS?

Tags: php, javascript, security, xss

Does this depend on if the input is going to be printed to the user? In my case I need to return the input back to the user (comments and bio).

Thanks!!!

Comment: Your main concern should be sanitizing user input, regardless of what your doing with it...  If you are using the input in ANY database queries you also need to escape it with the appropriate escaping algorithm...

Comment: @BrianPatterson: for using in database queries, only prepared statements give you proper security.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) is enough to prevent XSS.

Strip tags removes tags but not special characters like `"` or `'`, so if you use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) you also have to use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

If you want users' comments to be displayed like they typed them, don't use strip_tags, use htmlspecialchars() only.

Comment: I can´t speak for the downvoters, but your last line seems completely wrong; you should use `htmlspecialchars` always (when you output to the browser...) **except** when you want users to be able to execute code (like in jsbin)

Comment: @jeroen you missed the comma in `Use htmlspecialchars() only,`. It meant that if you want your users' comments to be displayed like they typed them, don't use strip_tags; use htmlspecialchars only.

Comment: so apparently my last phrase was a bit ambiguous :( I've edited.

Comment: Get it, I obviously read it differently than you meant it. Anyway, I agree.