# PHP htmlspecialchars() function shows html safe tags in page

Tags: php, html, tags, xss, htmlspecialchars

I have a form that users fill it and send their questions, and then administrator will answer them and finally these questions will be shown in website.
To prevent attacks, I've used **PDO** and **htmlspecialchars()** function. I don't apply any change on input data and only store them using PDO. But when I want to show them in the page, I use htmlspecialchars(). But this caused that even `<p>` tags appear in the text as part of it. What is the problem and how can I solve it?

**Storing questions:**

```
$stmt = "INSERT INTO tbl_questions (title,question) VALUES (?,?)";  
$q = $db->prepare($stmt);
$q->execute(array($_POST['title'],$_POST['question']));
```

**Displaying questions:**

```
echo htmlspecialchars($title).'<br />'.htmlspecialchars($question);
```

Comment: Why do you use `htmlspecialchars` to display the records? Shouldn't they be displayed otherwise?

Comment: to prevent XSS attacks

Comment: Then you ought to use `htmlspecialchars` when storing the question in the DB and `htmlspecialchars_decode` when `echo`ing it.

Comment: you can use [`strip_tags();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232793/should-i-use-both-striptags-and-htmlspecialchars-to-prevent-xss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `htmlspecialchars` is not perfect.

Take a look at [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). It is way more powerfull through whitelist filter. With it, your users can write html (such as `<p>`), and you don't have the risk of XSS.

consider, to use this, before you store it in the database, so you don't need to santize your input on every page view.

Comment: `strip_tags($title, '<p>');` will not remove `<p>` tag!!! It's for allowing tags!!

Comment: @ShaunakShukla my bad. Removed this part.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt your suggested solution is very well. But why htmlspecialchars() did not convert <p> to safe characters ?

Comment: @MohammadSaberi the method is save (the `<` and `>` are escaped to `&lt;` and `&gt;`). But problem is, as you described in the question that `<p>` will be displayed and not formated as paragraph. Technicaly the function replaces all "special html characters" to a display code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display only text, or even control which tags are converted/removed you have the option of using [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

```
echo strip_tags($title, '<p>');
```

Would display your title without having your `p` tags displayed.

**Edit: Also realize that even by allowing tags you also allow certain attributes to function normally which wouldn't keep you safe from XSS attacks.**

```
<p onclick="alert('xss scripting')">Awesome</p>
```

This would still work so using a filtering library such as [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) is recommended.

Comment: The second parameter is actually `allowable_tags`, so if it is `'<p>'`, then the `p`s would be displayed.

Comment: Well that was intended. I understand they wouldn't be "removed" I just meant they wouldn't be displayed as `&lt;p&gt;` to the viewer either because of `htmlspecialchars`

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem, you just didn't select a correct function for your task.
the `htmlspecialchars()` doesn't *remove* tags, it just transforms them so they are displayed instead of being executed. So, for example, `<p>` becomes `&lt;p&gt;`.
If you want to (partially) remove the tags, use the `strip_tags()` function. And, if you don't need these tags, you may (and should, I think) strip them before adding your content to database.
And also, you can allow certain tags, like this:

```
$q->execute(array(strip_tags($_POST['title']), strip_tags($_POST['question'], "<br><em>"));
```

This way you'll allow `<br>` and `<em>` in your questions. This is not needed, I'm just showing you the possibilities of the function.

However, if you want to use far more flexible rules, I'd suggest you an HTML sanitizer. For instance, I use [HTMLawed](http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/). It allows to specify not only allowed tags, but also allowed attributes and classes including wildcards (for instance, you can remove anything but the `class` attribute, or allow everything but the `style` attribute).

Comment: although I have used htmlspecialchars(), but it does not convert < and > to their &lt;p&gt;. When I see the source of page, I can see `<p>` exactly

Comment: Edited the answer adding a note about the HTML sanitizer I use.